# Paginating images from Flickr

Tags: php, flickr

I am trying to retrieve flickr images and show in my web page. Following [articles](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/search-for-photos-using-php-and-the-flickr-api/) I can show the images in my webpage. Now the problem is all the images are show in the first image- How I can do page paggination in php. I want to show only 6 images and rest are onsubsequently pages.

Code issue

```
$search = 'http://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' . $this->apikey . '&text=' . urlencode($query) . '&per_page=50&format=php_serial';
$result = file_get_contents($search);
$result_arr = unserialize($result);
```

In the above code I can get the all the images. What I need to do for paggination. Thank you for suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Flickr API docs](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), there is a `page` argument you can pass along with the `per_page` that you are already providing.

> **per_page** *(Optional)* - Number of photos to return per page. If this argument is omitted, it defaults to 100. The maximum allowed value is 500.
>
> **page** *(Optional)* - The page of results to return. If this argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.

So I would try altering the `&per_page=50` to be `&per_page=6` and adding an incrementable `page` argument:

```
$page = (int) $page // However you want to pass / generate this
$search = 'http://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' . $this->apikey . '&text=' . urlencode($query) . '&per_page=6&page=' . $page . '&format=php_serial';
```